# How to stop executing a MPI program in windows command prompt after infinite loop

Tags: command-prompt, message-passing, windows-console, mpich

I'm new to MPI programming. I'm in basic stage. So I use this command to run the program

```
mpirun -np 4 try
```

And this executes my program. I'm using MPICH NT. When I miss something an infinite loop starts. Suppose
I fumbled with `MPI_Send` & `MPI_Recv` like

```
MPI_Send(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 1, DEFAULT_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Recv(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 15, DEFAULT_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

source & destination are wrong. Now while executing this command prompt froze. It doesn't allow me to do anything just froze. Then I had to restart the command prompt, again go to the directory etc. Imagine 50 times doing that..... How can I avoid restarting the command prompt? Is there any easy way to recover from the hung mode?

Comment: surely this is a duplicate?  the process sends, waiting for a receive.  the receive never happens because the process is sending.  use non-blocking operations.

Comment: I don't know what mpirun is, but most console programs respond to Ctrl+C to terminate operation.  If that doesn't work, you can always kill mpirun.exe from task manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc)

Comment: @RobLatham I know what it is. Question was how to recover this situation without shutting down the command prompt?

Comment: @RyanBemrose Okay I'll give them a shot as soon as I can

Comment: @RyanBemrose  post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most console programs respond to `Ctrl+C` to terminate operation. If that doesn't work, you can always kill mpirun.exe from task manager (`Ctrl+Shift+Esc`)